# Pass a Json value to Laravel Blade

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-blade

Can anyone tell me how to pass a json object into view?
I have tried converting my response into an array, collection but cannot pass a value into blade.
Im using Guzzle as my HTTP client.

Controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $client = new Client();
        $get = $client->request('GET', 'http://api.domain.com/v1/', 
            ['headers' => ['Accept' => 'application/json']]);
        $data = $get->getBody()->getContents();

        //dd($data);

        return view('dashboard', compact('data'));

    }
```

JSON Response:

```
{
"2020-05-29 - 2020-05-29": {
"86xxx3": {
"widgetId": 863003,
"siteId": 560890,
"impressions": 5766,
"realImpressions": 2671,
"visibilityRate": 46,
"clicks": 125,
"ctr": "2.17",
"revenue": "2.00",
"cpc": "1.60",
"cpm": "0.35"
}
}
}
```

How to get into blade only Revenue for example?

Comment: Well basically you can use it as an object like we to in blade, but the `key` `value` representation is wrong. The root level `key` should not look like this. The `JSON` response should be better than this.